# Bottle Framework SqlAlchemy Type Error: object not iterable

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, bottle

I am trying to write a REST api using the bottle framework. My base class CRUD has two methods. 
The base query does the query and the get_values method iterates through the result and returns the data. But I am getting the object not iterable error.

```
class InfluencerCrud(CrudObject):
def base_query(self, db_session, request_params):

    return db_session.query(Groups, GroupLeaders, Users) \
            .filter(GroupLeaders.id == Groups.group_leaders_id) \
            .filter(Users.id == GroupLeaders.users_id )

def get_values(self, db_session, request_params, raw_result):
    logging.error(raw_result)
    for group, group_leader, user in raw_result:
        data = as_dict(group, include_columns = ['clicks_estimated', 'completeness', 'cpc', 'created_at',
                                                 'description', 'guid','languages_id', 'name', 'registration_status',
                                                 'size', 'url', 'verticals_id'])
        data['addresses_id'] = user.addresses_id
        data['user'] = as_dict(user, include_columns = ["addresses_id", "created_at", "education_id", "email",
                                                        "email_verified_at", "gender", "income_id", "marital_status_id",
                                                        "name_first", "name_last", "phone", "status", "updated_at", "worK_status_id"])
        data['user']['race_id'] = []
        c = session.query(UserHasRace.race_id).filter(UserHasRace.user_id == user.id)
        for r, in c:
            data['user']['race_id'].append(r)
        data['user']['children'] = []
        c = session.query(UserChildren).filter(UserChildren.user_id == user.id)
        for r in c:
            data['user']['children'].append(get_dict_obj(r))
        picurl = None
        up = session.query(UserPicture).filter(UserPicture.id == user.pictures_id).first()
        if up != None and up.file_name != None:
            i = up.file_name.rfind('/')
            picurl = linqia.system.config.avatars.s3_url + 'user_pictures/' + up.file_name[i + 1:]
        data['user']['picture_url'] = picurl
        return data
```

Following is the error

> File "/home/linqia-api-internal/current/api-internal/source/influencers/influencer.py", line 42, in get_values
>   [Tue Feb 14 20:41:10 2017] [error] [client ::1]     for group, group_leader, user in raw_result:
>   [Tue Feb 14 20:41:10 2017] [error] [client ::1] TypeError: 'Groups' object is not iterable

When I tried to print the raw data I am getting references to all the three objects. I am just not getting to iterate them.

Any help would be appreciated, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Got a fix. 
My get_values function was calling for every query I was making, so as a result, it was a tuple of all the queries I made (groups, groupleaders, users)
So I had to access it as a tuple.